# Is there a system of multivariable polynomials with a solution in a field extension of $\mathbb{C}$ but not $\mathbb{C}$ itself?

Tags: field-theory

Does there exist a set $\{f_i(x_1, ..., x_n)\}_{i \in I}$ of n-variable polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$ such that the set of equations $\{f_i(x_1, ..., x_n) = 0\}_{i \in I}$ is not satisfied by any n-tuplet $(x_1, ..., x_n) \in \mathbb{C}^n$, but is satisfied in $F^n$ for some field extension $F$ of $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: No. With $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ a solution one approach is to say that there is always a morphism $\phi:\Bbb{C}[a_1,\ldots,a_n]\to \Bbb{C}$ so the $\phi(a_j)$ are complex solutions.

Comment: $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, so every non constant polynomial has a zero in $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Weak nullstellansatz tells you that the $f_i$ have a common zero xor they generate the unit ideal; in the latter case if you do a field extension they still generate the unit ideal so they can't have a common zero because $0\neq 1$.  For the intuition behind this I suggest reading the first few paragraphs of https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/11/26/hilberts-nullstellensatz/

Comment: @Oria This is a system of multivariable polynomials that all have to be satisfied at once. So that argument doesn't work.